# Microsoft Edge - autocomplete on input field

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

Some users are reporting that Microsoft Edge is opening a weird popup by pressing `/` on the input field:

[image]
(sorry for the Italian text).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vLobfq92/ press `/` in the input field using Microsoft Edge

I can't find any API or DOM attribute to avoid this, I tried `autocomplete="off"` and other, but nothing and if there is a browser option to set we can't ask all users to do this.

Comment: This seems to be happens witn MS Edge only. Microsoft ruin the standard again since IE?

Comment: Try with autocomplete="nope"

Comment: With nope the issue persists, and yes MS Edge only...

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in Edge. I suggest that you can provide feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge. The Edge team will check the feedback and improve the product continuously. Thanks for your understanding.